# Laravel event not called inside job handle

Tags: laravel, events, jobs, broadcast

I havesome quiz game with laravel.
When game get started, it dispach a job with 60s delay.
in 60s users can answer the question, after 60s  job will calculate whos answer is right and send broadcast to all users in the chat room. 
The problem is it never broadcast anything, neither showing error.
This is code inside job handle

```
public function handle(){
    ....
    event(new RoomMessage($message, $user)); // its ignored
    \Log::debug("End Job"); // its work
    ....
}
```

EDIT: my queue driver is database, and my broadcast driver using Redis

Comment: Can you add the code for your `RoomMessage` class.

Comment: The problem is it never broadcast anything, neither showing error. How do you know that, do you have a listener or?